# Find $P(Y \leq y)$ and $P(Z \geq z)$ where $Y$ the largest and $Z$ the smallest numbered ball of a sample of size $n$ from a box with $r$ balls.

Tags: probability

Suppose a box contains $r$ balls numbered from $1$ to $r$. A random sample of size $n$ is selected without replacement. Let $Y$ be the largest number observed in the sample and $Z$ the smallest.

Find $P(Y \leq y)$ and $P(Z \geq z)$.

In the first I tried to list all possible values, and seems like a sum of $\frac{1}{n}$ probabilities for each value of $y$, so an answer could be $P(X \leq y) = \frac{y}{n}$ but I don't know for sure.
In similar, the second could be $ = 1 - \frac{z}{n} = \frac{n-z}{n}$, it's difficult to be sure, could anyone help?

Comment: Sorry if seems too easy, I only want some help if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

$P(Y \leq y) = \frac{\begin{pmatrix}y \\ n\end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix}r \\ n\end{pmatrix}}$ and 
$P(Z \geq z) = \frac{\begin{pmatrix}r-z+1 \\ n\end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix}r \\ n\end{pmatrix}}$

By techniques of counting only, not very elucidative.